# To implement the magento quick login

Tags: magento, authentication

I have install the Quick Login extension. I have followed the instruction to use the extension. I copy the code from app/design/frontend/default/default/quicklogin/top.links.phtml. i use the following code on the top of my screen to login or register, but i could not get any result.

```
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <?php if($_link->getLabel() != 'Log In'): ?>
        <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) :?>

     <li><a class="top-link-last" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login / Register') ?>" id="alogin" href="javascript:void(0)" ><?php echo $this->__('Login / Register') ?></a></li>
     <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the problem ? you added some HTML and you're not seeing it in your site that's it ? Check you're putting the HTML in the good package/module. Empty your caches

Comment: Hi Bixi, I already disable my cache. I can see the Login and register link on the top of screen. But it did not work as the extension explain. So is there any setting i missed. Please help me.

Comment: I suggest you to contact the extension maker ...